# Proper CSS syntax multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

This works fine:

```
ul.tabs a.current:hover {
    background-position: -420px -31px;  
    color:#000; 
}
```

but this dosent

```
ul.tabs a.commentArea.current:hover {
     background-position: -420px -31px; 
     color:#000; 
    }
```

Im getting the indication that I wrote this style incorrectly, as the css isnt working on my element. How would I write this correctly...proper syntax?

Comment: Your edited CSS code is correct. Do you actually have `<a class="commentArea current">`?

Comment: Ive got it working now...had to remove the space before :hover

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
a.commentArea:hover
```

selectors targeting the same element must not be separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

no space before :hover

```
ul.tabs a.commentArea:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.tabs a.commentArea:hover
```

Remove the space before :hover

See http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp